# leaflet.js jquery add LayerControls to Jquery UI Tab Component

Tags: jquery, tabs, controls, leaflet, layer

Please see this: http://gisdev.clemson.edu/fireflies/indexpulldown.php

What I need to accomplish is to place the map's controls, which can be seen inside with box on top right as checkboxes and radio buttons, inside the Jquery UI tab component. These controls are currently added to the map via: `map.addControl(layersControl);` calls.

I am thinking of, somehow, adding this control to one of the jquery 'tabs'; say:  `<div id="#div_tab_legends">` but doing `div_tab_legends.innertHtml = layersControl` doesn't work; the layersControl is an object.

If I could, maybe, duplicate the layersControl's entire html into the div_tab_legends div then it may work?

It is possible there is quite an easier way. But I can't find anything in Leaflet documentation or other online sources to have the jquery's ui tab components to do the needed.

Any idea?
Thanks!

**update** I think I am getting closer following: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leaflet-js/1YvGltqTSm0

Answer (score 0):

Here is how ended up fixing the problem:

```
 $( "#div_layer_controls" ).append( $( ".leaflet-control-layers-expanded" ) );
```

per http://api.jquery.com/append/

So basically the everything under the class `.leaflet-control-layers-expanded` was moved (not copied) to the desired div.

Thanks.